# Regular expression negative look ahead

Tags: regex

Not too familiar at RE.  I have the following string

```
"The cat jump The cat ran The cat eat The dog jump The dog ran The dog eat".
```

I want to get

```
"The cat ran" and "The dog ran".
```

I thought this RE using negative look ahead should work

```
"The(?!.*The).*jump"
```

but it's not.  What is missing?

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need a negative lookahead? The simpler regex `"The (cat|dog) ran"` should work just fine.

Comment: That's true.  I was actually simplifying my real task.  How would I do it with negative look ahead.

Comment: regex syntax varies depending on what dialect you are using. You should probably tell what programming language or programs your expressions need to run in.

Comment: I'll bump this to mention that if your task is more complicated than what you have provided us with (for which there is a trivial simplification), you should probably include more of your task so we can come up with something that better fits the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want an expression that matches a substring that does not contain `The`.
That can be done with a construct like `(?:(?!The).)*`, in your expression:

```
The(?:(?!The).)*jump
```

Note that in this case using lazy (`.*?`) quantifiers would suffice, eg:

```
The.*?jump
```

Maybe that can work on your original problem too.

Comment: Nice! the first construct worked beautifully.  The second did not.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following do it for you?

```
The \w* ran
```